# Building jEdit In Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, jedit

I have been trying to build Jedit from this link 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jedit/files/jedit-devel/4.3pre9/
with intellij
however
when I try to compile the following error appears many times

[image]

and when I oh try to import the libraries from maven I only get errors because its impossible to import from them for some reason
anyone has a quite quick or efficient guide on how to do it ?

Comment: You need to [define libraries](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html#define-library) and [set them for the modules](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html#add-library-to-module-dependencies).

Comment: I tried that doesnt work for maven is nt letting me get the library

Answer (score 0):

Execute the `retrieve` Ant target, that downloads all libraries you need to build everything to `lib/` if you didn't configure a different directory.

Those files you then can add in IntelliJ as libraries.

Besides that, adding `org` as source directory with `org` package prefix is enough. The other sources like the `Ar` where you have the problem are just infrastructure code like custom Ant tasks or the installer to build a distribution.

Actually, the only dependency you need for the code in `org` is `jsr305` for the nullability annotations. No other libraries are used in the main jEdit code.